# .NET core console app in Framework AppService

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-appservice

Can I deploy a .Net Core 6 based Console app as Webjob in a Azure app service with .Net framework teck stack ?

Answer (score 0):

- Visual Studio 2022 support .NET 6.0.
- **Visual studio 2022** version **17.0** required to develop .Net 6.0 console application.
- The net6.0 Target Framework Moniker (TFM) provides access to all of.cross-platform NET's APIs.
- If you're developing console apps, ASP.NET Core apps, or reusable cross-platform frameworks, this is the best solution.

### Steps

- Creating the Web Job

[image]
[image]

- create a `“Run.Cmd”` file and add , _`dotnet AzureWebJob.dll_` to it.
- run `_dotnet publish -c release_`
- Deploying the Web Job
- In the Azure Portal =>Your App = > select “WebJobs”= > Add web Job and save

Please refer [Create Web job using .NET 6](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-web-jobs-in-azure-app-services/) and  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs) for more information